# How to delete agent pool in Visual Studio Team Services

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I want to delete or change an existing Agent Pool from the Visual Studio Team Service. All the agents from the pool are already deleted. If I go to Settings->Agent Pools , there is only an option for "New pool...". Is it possible to delete an old one?

Answer (score 2):

On the Settings->Agent Pools, for each Pool Name on its right there is a small black triangle pointing down, left click on it, a context menu will appear, last menu item is 'Delete', click on that the Agent Pool will be gone after a confirmation dialog.

Comment: I'll accpet it later. I'm new user and still don't have reputation.